# Converting bibliographic record from RUSMARC to MARC21

Tags: bibliography, marc

I have a bibliographic record in RUSMARC (Russian UNIMARC) standard. For further processing I need to convert this record into MARCXML (MARC21 in XML) format.

How to accomplish such a tranformation programmatically?

**UPDATE**
I have some routine to read and parse ISO 2709 format. However, RUSMARC (and UNIMARC in general) is different to MARC21 in terms of fields meaning.

Comment: What have you tried?  It sounds like you need to parse RUSMARC into a datastructure of some sort and then write that out as XML.  So, start with the first part and ask questions where you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you, @Iguananaut. I have added some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNIMARC records should be converted to MARC21 according to specifications published by Library of Congress (http://www.loc.gov/marc/unimarctomarc21.html).

First, you need to read your RUSMARC (UNIMARC) record into memory and construct XML according to UNISlim schema (http://www.rusmarc.ru/shema/UNISlim.xsd).

Then you can use XSL transformation that converts UNIMARC XML (in UNISlim schema) into MARCXML.

You can git this XSL transformation here: https://github.com/edsd/biblio-metadata